# How to prevent a dialog from leaving parent bounds?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a window that shows a draggable dialog, however I don't want the dialog to leave the bounds of the parent window.

```
using (var dialog = new MyDialog())
{
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't. Let the user do what he want or needs.

Comment: @TaW is right.  You said "parent window", but your code does not show parenting:  `dialog.MDIParent = this`, or some such thing.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Sorry, I'm still learning WinForms and feel like a real newbie when working with it. I have passed in `this` in the `ShowDialog(this)` method to identify that the current Form is the Parent, and I was looking to find out if there is an easy way to limit the dialog to the parent form's bounds only.

Comment: My comment was an attempt to illicit a response as to whether you want a strangely handcuffed, yet not-so-separate form, or if you really want a true MDI parent-child relationship.  Which would have the characteristic of one form inside of another.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I was looking for something more like a MDI parent-child relationship. It's for something small, so I was hoping I could just do something hack-ish to get it working without messing with MDI frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to overwrite the dialog form's `WndProc` method and monitor the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` system message for a new position and size:

```
public class DialogForm : Form
{
    private struct WindowPos
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public uint flags;
    }

    public DialogForm()
    {
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;
        if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
        {
            WindowPos mwp = (WindowPos)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WindowPos));
            if (mwp.hwnd == Handle)
            {
                const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
                const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
                int x = mwp.x;
                int y = mwp.y;
                if (x < Owner.Left || y < Owner.Top || x + mwp.cx > Owner.Right || y + mwp.cy > Owner.Bottom)
                {
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                    mwp.flags |= SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(mwp, m.LParam, true);
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**EDIT.** For more smoothness use this method:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;
    if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
    {
        WindowPos mwp = (WindowPos)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof (WindowPos));
        if (mwp.hwnd == Handle)
        {
            int x = mwp.x;
            int y = mwp.y;
            if (x < Owner.Left || y < Owner.Top || x + mwp.cx > Owner.Right || y + mwp.cy > Owner.Bottom)
            {
                bool resizing = mwp.cx != Width || mwp.cy != Height;
                if (resizing)
                {
                    if (x < Owner.Left)
                    {
                        mwp.x = x = Owner.Left;
                        mwp.cx = Width;
                    }
                    if (y < Owner.Top)
                    {
                        mwp.y = y = Owner.Top;
                        mwp.cy = Height;
                    }

                    if (mwp.cx > Owner.Right - x)
                        mwp.cx = Owner.Right - x;
                    if (mwp.cy > Owner.Bottom - y)
                        mwp.cy = Owner.Bottom - y;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (x < Owner.Left)
                        mwp.x = Owner.Left;
                    else if (x > Owner.Right - mwp.cx)
                        mwp.x = Owner.Right - mwp.cx;

                    if (y < Owner.Top)
                        mwp.y = Owner.Top;
                    else if (y > Owner.Bottom - mwp.cy)
                        mwp.y = Owner.Bottom - mwp.cy;
                }
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(mwp, m.LParam, true);
            }
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Its not very smooth, however it does work. I'll see what I can do to modify the code so it runs a bit smoother, otherwise I'll try an alternate approach to this task. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly what is smoothness in this case, a smoother method was added.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry :) I'm working remotely today and apparently the remote connection handles window dragging differently, and I'm off all next week, but I'll give this a try when I get back. Based on what I see so far, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.